# Split sentence on a list of alternative whole words preserving "splitter words"

Tags: c#, regex

I'm stumped.

```
I went to the store at the mall at seven thirty in a big huff.
```

Expecting Regex.Split to yeild

- I went
- to the store
- at the mall
- at seven thirty
- in a big huff.

My sorry first attempt is: `\bto\b|\bat\b|\bin\b` which captures the prepositions.

The next attempt consumes the whole sentence:

```
\bto\b([a-zA-Z ]*)|\bat\b([a-zA-Z ]*)|\bin\b([a-zA-Z ]*)
```

And like they say, I had a problem so I chose regex and now I have a drinking problem.

Comment: did you try something like that: `(?=\b(?:to|at|in)\b)` as a split pattern?

Comment: That appears to work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the input according to the below regex which uses [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Lookaheads are zero width assertions which won't consume any characters but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

```
@"\s(?=to\b|at\b|in\b)"
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/fG1vD4/5)

**Code:**

```
string value = "I went to the store at the mall at seven thirty in a big huff.";
string[] lines = Regex.Split(value, @"\s(?=to\b|at\b|in\b)");
foreach (string line in lines) {
Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/qmn2qg)

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=\bto\b)|(?=\bat\b)|(?=\bin\b)
```

Try this.Use this in your regex.split function.Replace by `\n`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/11